# What is the shortcut to delete the first word in a camelCase named word?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode, If I had a word like this `helloWorldFromMoon`, and my cursor is at the first of the word, is there is a shortcut I can use to delete just the word `hello` so that I end up with `WorldFromMoon` ?

I'm no talking about `ctrl` + `del`, that would delete the entire word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `deleteWordPartRight` is what you are looking for, it is unbound by default.  You could make a keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) like so:

```
{
  "key": "alt+right",               // what binding you want here
  "command": "deleteWordPartRight"
},
```